# What card game is this? 4 cards per player faced down

Tags: identify-this-game, playing-cards

When I visited Bulgaria, someone taught me a game, he called “kabum” ( not sure if that's how you write it).

- 2 or more players.
- each player receives 4 cards faced down and need to arrange them in a formation to last till the end of the game ( side by side...). Everyone can only look at 1 of their cards and then return it to the same position.

Each card has a value (A=0, 2=2...,J=-1,Q=12,K=1) and the objective of the game is to finish with the minimum amount of points. When you have 5 points or less you can say Kabum to start the last round.

- When you buy a card you can either discard or substitute it with one of your own, placing it in the same position, that way you can start knowing your cards.
- Some cards have some powers when you discard:

  - Cards with 7: You can look at one of your cards
  - Cards with 8: Look at one of your opponents cards
  - Cards with 9: Exchange cards with someone without looking
  - Cards with 10: Look at one card and change it

I believe these rules must vary.

But that the game:

- Less points
- Same position always faced down
- Change cards

There are more rules but I believe this is enough to someone that knows the game to identify it.

Answer (score 7):

It's an actual remake of "Golf" and it's name is [Kabo!](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabo_(game))

Answer (score 3):

Sound like a variant of the card game Golf, which has you using 6 cards to do about the same thing.  Everything else seem to line up.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golf_(card_game)

Answer (score 3):

We know it by the name of COBO. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabo_(game)

Similar rules, difference is: 
1. Every card has a value of the number written on the card.
2. Powers are in batches. Eg. 7-8 can be used to view your own card, 9-10: replacement without revealing, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds very similar to the game 'Beverbende': https://www.999games.nl/beverbende.html

This is a Dutch game, I'm unsure if there's any translated version of it. Reading your description, I think 'Beverbende' itself was derived from 'Kabol'.