# I want to know the correct name of this cards game

Tags: identify-this-game

I played a card game.
My teacher told me how to play it, but she said "it is good not to say at school" didn't tell me the correctly name. she just tell me she call it "Oh no".
this game is making small numbers,
K=0 A=1 2=2(it is same to 10) J=10 Q=10
the rule of it is below.

1. it starts from 4 cards per person. these 4 need to be face down.
2. Players can see 2 of the cards.
3. place the remaining card in a pile and reveal the top card.
4. the first player replace the card, or pile and reveal the top card and replace the card or throw the card on revealed card
5. continue 3 and 4
6. when one of a players thought "my card is good condition" they can knock the table
7. the game is finishes after other player did one more play
8. the winner is who got smallest point

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golf_(card_game)#Four-card_golf maybe? see also https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/44673/what-card-game-is-this-4-cards-per-player-faced-down

Comment: While it's _not_ that game, I'm wondering if your teacher mistakenly thought this was [Shithead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shithead_(card_game)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is **Cabo** with a standard deck. Other names include Cambio, Pablo and Cactus.

Gameplay: (from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabo_(game)))

> Each player is dealt 4 cards, face down. After each deal, players may
> peek at any 2 of their own cards.
>
> In clockwise order, players do any of three things:
>
> 1. pick a card from the draw pile, and either keep the card (placing one
>    of their own cards on the discard pile) or discard it (if the card
>    drawn and discarded is a choice card, the choice card can be used if
>    so desired).
> 2. pick a card from the discard pile and place one of their
>    own cards on the discard pile
> 3. call "Cabo"